# Several's instances of a component in angular 2/4 called from differents html page

Tags: angular, components

I would like to know , how can I create several instance of a component in my app?

For example, I have a component that represents a table which display data dynamically.

This table send an event to the component which called it.

Now if I have several's components which call this table , so all these component will get the event.

So I would like to separate all instance of this table to not conflict them.

Is it possible to do it ?Or there is another way to achieve the dynamic table ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK , my option for solution to this problem :

To implement **'OnDestroy' and 'OnInit'** Functions in every component we use this dynamic compontent .

On 'OnInit' to associate the subscribe to variable and then to subscribe to event from this component.

On 'OnDetroy' to unsubscribe from this event by this variable.